# PHP IMAP Mailbox Processing - Loop on MessageNo?

Tags: php, email, imap

A quick question, but one I can't seem to find a solid answer on anywhere. I'm using PHP IMAP to process messages in a mailbox, but I'm using a loop based on imap_num_msg to process them.

```
$imap = imap_open("{imap.test.com:143}INBOX", "test@test.com", "password");
$message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $message_count; ++$i) 
{ "Processing Code using $i" }
imap_expunge($imap);
imap_close($imap);
```

Is this the correct way of processing, or should I be fetching an array of UID's for each message? If I stick with this code, what happens when a new message comes in, will the order of the messages change and effect the loop?

Comment: New emails always appear at the end.  However, you should be more worried about deleted messages...  There are some safeguards in the RFC to prevent reordering of message sequence numbers while performing tasks like these.  .. My advice would be to always use UIDs if you can, if that is sufficient for your application.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend to fetch the uids as well which can help in keeping a log of mails which are already been downloaded. as asked by ansh also r u planning to perform this fetch everytime a user logs-in???

Answer (score 0):

The code would run fine. UID once created remains intact unless the state of mailbox changes.
But are you planning to do this every time bcoz mails once downloaded on client need not be downloaded again.